# Is it possible to use an array entry in a #selector?

Tags: swift, button, selector

I'm adding labels and buttons to a TextView dynamically. This is driven by looping through arrays containing label names, button names, and button function names. For brevity and simplicity, I've changed the code here to use hard-coded indexes rather than a loop, and I did not include the label- and button-creation functions. The labels are created just fine. The first button is also created just fine, since I specify Button1Clicked as the #selector argument. The second button is created correctly only if I specify Button2Clicked as the #selector argument. If I attempt to reference an array in the button #selector argument, I receive the compiler error "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer". Assuming it is possible to use an array containing the @objc function name as an argument to the #selector, can someone please provide the appropriate syntax for me? I'm using Swift 5 and Xcode 11.2. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
@objc func Button1Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("You pressed button 1")
}

@objc func Button2Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    print("You pressed button 2")
}
    .
    .
    .

    var labelNames = [UILabel]()
    let Label1:UILabel = UILabel()
    let Label2:UILabel = UILabel()
    labelNames = [Label1, Label2]

    var buttonNames = [UIButton]()
    let Button1:UIButton = UIButton()
    let Button2:UIButton = UIButton()
    buttonNames = [Button1, Button2]

    let buttonSelectorNames = ["Button1Clicked", "Button2Clicked"]

    configureLabel(labelNameIn: labelNames[0],
                   textIn: "aaaaa",
               textColorIn: appColorWhite,
                   backgroundColorIn: appColorBlue,
                   yPositionIn: 0)
    statusTextview.addSubview(labelNames[0])

    configureLabel(labelNameIn: labelNames[1],
                   textIn: "-- bbbbb",
                   textColorIn: appColorWhite,
               backgroundColorIn: appColorBlue,
                   yPositionIn: 25)
    statusTextview.addSubview(labelNames[1])

    configureButton(buttonNameIn: buttonNames[0],
                    xPositionIn: 0,
                    yPositionIn: 50,
                    textIn: "B1",
                    textColorIn: appColorBlack,
                    backgroundColorIn: appColorBrightGreen,
                    textViewIn: statusTextview)
    buttonNames[0].addTarget(self,
                             action: #selector(Button1Clicked),
                             for: .touchUpInside)
    statusTextview.addSubview(buttonNames[0])

    configureButton(buttonNameIn: buttonNames[1],
                    xPositionIn: 100,
                    yPositionIn: 50,
                    textIn: "B2",
                    textColorIn: appColorBlack,
                    backgroundColorIn: appColorBrightGreen,
                    textViewIn: statusTextview)
    buttonNames[1].addTarget(self,
                      action: #selector(buttonSelectorNames[1]),
                      for: .touchUpInside)
    statusTextview.addSubview(buttonNames[1])
```

Comment: The problem is that `buttonSelectorNames` is an array of strings, not an array of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you don’t need to define button click event for each button.you can define common function and assign it to all buttons in the loop.then you can specify through button tag

in your loop assign the current index as button tag

```
buttonNames[currentIndex].tag = currentIndex
buttonNames[currentIndex].addTarget(self,
                             action: #selector(didButtonClicked(_ :)),
                             for: .touchUpInside)
```

button click function

```
@objc func didButtonClicked(_ sender : UIButton){
        switch sender.tag{
        case 0: //clicked button with tag 0
        case 1: //clicked button with tag 1
        default: break
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have a deal with the same type of requirement. I was doing it by storing the `selector` in `Array`.

Please refer to the code snippets. I am sure it will help you.

## Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let selector = [#selector(Button1Clicked),#selector(Button2Clicked)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let btn = UIButton(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: selector[0], for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func Button1Clicked(){
        print("Button1Clicked")
    }

    @objc func Button2Clicked(){

    }
}
```

## Output:

[image: Output]